# Why can't I search a list of automatically generated objects for their attributes?

Tags: python, list, attributes

First of all, I try to implement a very simple Online-Shop.
So I have a product generator which generates 10 product objects and appends them in a list called all_products.

```
def products_generator(self):
    product_categories = ["Trousers", "Pullover", "T-Shirts", "Shorts", "Hats", "Jacket"]
    product_names = ["Sellateen", "Piffen", "Ivory", "Petal", "Suave", "Patron", "Dawn", "Paramour", "Palace",
                     "Tee", "Chique", "Babo"]
    for i in range(0, 10):
        ID = len(self.all_products) + 1000
        category = random.choice(product_categories)
        name = random.choice(product_names)
        description = self.description_generator(category)
        price_excl_tax = random.randrange(20, 300, 10)
        price_incl_tax = round(price_excl_tax * 1.19, 2)
        stock = random.randrange(10, 200, 1)
        self.create_product(ID, category, name, description, price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock)

def create_product(self, ID, category, name, description, price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock):
    new_product = Product(ID=ID, category=category, name=name, description=description,
                          price_excl_tax=price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax=price_incl_tax, stock=stock)
    self.all_products.append(new_product)
```

So all generated objects are stored in all_products and I can print them in the console but I can´t search for them in the list. I have also implemented a add_to_cart() to put them in a cart list, but find_product() returns None when I want to return a generated object.

```
def add_to_cart(self, product_id, quantity):  
    product = self.find_product(product_id)
    if product is not None:
        if product.stock >= quantity:
            for x in range(0, int(quantity)):
                self.user_cart.append(product)
        else:
            print("Sorry, we only have ", product.stock, " in stock.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, no such named product found.")

def find_product(self, product_id):
    for product in self.all_products:
        if product.ID == product_id:
            return product
```

But when I manually add a product object I can find it with their attribute. :/

Here my class Product:

```
class Product:
    ID = None
    category = None
    name = None
    description = None
    price_excl_tax = None
    price_incl_tax = None
    stock = None

    def __init__(self, ID, category, name, description, price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock):
        self.ID = ID
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.price_excl_tax = price_excl_tax
        self.price_incl_tax = price_incl_tax
        self.stock = stock

    def print_product(self):
        print("Product information:\n", "ID: ", self.ID, "\n", "Category: ",
              self.category, "\n", "Name: ", self.name, "\n", "Description: ", self.description, "\n", "Price excl. tax: ",
              self.price_excl_tax, "€\n", "Price incl. tax: ", self.price_incl_tax, "€\n", "Stock:", self.stock)
```

Comment: What's the `type` of `product_id`?

Comment: the type should be an int but I didn´t defined it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your info, I tried to replicate it. See below a working version.

```
class Product:

  def __init__(self, ID, category, name, description, price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock):
    self.ID = ID
    self.category = category
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.price_excl_tax = price_excl_tax
    self.price_incl_tax = price_incl_tax
    self.stock = stock

  def print_product(self):
    print("Product information:\n", "ID: ", self.ID, "\n", "Category: ",
          self.category, "\n", "Name: ", self.name, "\n", "Description: ", self.description, "\n", "Price excl. tax: ",
          self.price_excl_tax, "€\n", "Price incl. tax: ", self.price_incl_tax, "€\n", "Stock:", self.stock)

class Inventory:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.all_products = {}
        self.user_cart = {}
        # fill the inventory
        self.products_generator()

  def products_generator(self):
    product_categories = ["Trousers", "Pullover", "T-Shirts", "Shorts", "Hats", "Jacket"]
    product_names = ["Sellateen", "Piffen", "Ivory", "Petal", "Suave", "Patron", "Dawn", "Paramour", "Palace",
                    "Tee", "Chique", "Babo"]
    for i in range(0, 10):
        ID = len(self.all_products) + 1000
        category = random.choice(product_categories)
        name = random.choice(product_names)
        # description = self.description_generator(category) I don't have info on that function
        price_excl_tax = random.randrange(20, 300, 10)
        price_incl_tax = round(price_excl_tax * 1.19, 2)
        stock = random.randrange(10, 200, 1)
        self.create_product(ID, category, name, "description", price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock)

  def create_product(self, ID, category, name, description, price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax, stock):
    new_product = Product(ID=ID, category=category, name=name, description=description,
                        price_excl_tax=price_excl_tax, price_incl_tax=price_incl_tax, stock=stock)
    #using a dictionary instead of a list for easier search
    self.all_products[ID] = new_product

  def add_to_cart(self, product_id, quantity):  
    product = self.find_product(product_id)
    if product is not None:
        if product.stock >= quantity:
            # store the quantity of each product in the cart instead of duplicating the product object
            if product_id in self.user_cart:
                self.user_cart[product_id] += quantity
            else:
                self.user_cart[product_id] = quantity
        else:
            print("Sorry, we only have ", product.stock, " in stock.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, no such named product found.")

  def find_product(self, product_id):
    if product_id in self.all_products:
        return self.all_products[product_id]
    else:
        print(f"The product ID {product_id} does not exist")
        return None
```

Comment: I have built the project according to the MVC pattern and use oop. So I have a class product and a product controller with the lists all_products & user_cart and all the mapped functions. I have also thought of storing the objects as dictionaries, but can dictionaries be stored in lists?

Comment: From what you have added, I am not sure why you have class attributes and instance attributes with the same name. It may not be the source of your issues but I would remove the class attributes (the ones at None) as they are shared over all instances and it would probably create issues. [info on that](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/differences-between-class-attribute-and-instance-attribute-of-python-1ae61774489c#:~:text=in%20this%20post%3A-,Do%20not%20use%20the%20same%20name%20for%20instance%20attributes%20and,objects%20to%20avoid%20unintended%20results.)

Comment: When you call `find_product` you should try to print `self.all_products` to see what you are iterating on.  
PS: yes you can store dictionnaries in a list but that is not what I meant, I meant replace your `all_products` list by a dictionnary with the format `{"ID1": Product() , "ID2": Product(), ...}` this way you can access each product by its ID directly without a loop using `all_products["ID2"]`